# When to use an article with a noun and when not

Tags: article

Slow German Podcast #183 has the following sentence:

> Als Geheimdienst versuchte die Stasi herauszufinden, ob das Ausland der DDR gefährlich werden könnte.

No article before Geheimdienst. Adding an article before Geheimdienst, according to Google Translate, gives the sentence an entirely different meaning.

Then in Podcast #176 the following sentences occur:

> Mit fünf Jahren begann Albert, Geige zu spielen.

No article before Geige.

> Als Teenager verließ er die Schule ohne Abschluss und zog nach Mailand.

No article with Teenager or Abschluss.

> Ihm waren die Menschenrechte wichtig.

An article before Menschenrechte.

> Er war für die Gleichheit aller Menschen.

An article before Gleichheit.

I do not see a pattern here to account for the use or non-use of articles. Is it arbitrary or would these sentences be wrong without these particular choices made regarding the use/non-use of the articles?

Comment: Google translate isn't a good tutor. If you really feel you had to get help from an online translator for German, use *DeepL*. But that one may put you into even more troubles as it fails in more sophisticated ways only native speakers of the target language can uncover.

Comment: Google translate is on par with deepl as of now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences are subtle in all cases. Most times no article means the noun is an additional description or kind, the indefinite article means its one piece among others and the definite article is a pointing finger, similar to a demonstrative pronoun.

> Als Geheimdienst versuchte die Stasi herauszufinden, …

*As **a typical** intelligence agency the Stasi tried to find out, …*

> Als **ein** Geheimdienst versuchte die Stasi herauszufinden, …

*As **one** intelligence agency (among others) the Stasi tried to find out, …*

> Als **der** Geheimdienst versuchte die Stasi herauszufinden, …

*As **that one** intelligence agency the Stasi tried to find out, …*

---

> Mit fünf Jahren begann Albert, Geige zu spielen.

It's about *Geige* as a kind of instrument he learned to play.

> Mit fünf Jahren begann Albert, eine Geige zu spielen.

It's about one special violine. How odd.

> Mit fünf Jahren begann Albert, die Geige zu spielen.

This is like the first variant, but with a pointing finger.

---

> Als Teenager verließ er die Schule ohne Abschluss und zog nach Mailand.

It's the same as above. *Teenager* is a state he was in, a kind of person. *Ohne Abschluss* is a method of leaving the school, a kind of method. It's not about a single *Abschluss* but about the method of leaving.

---

> Ihm waren die Menschenrechte wichtig.
>
> Er war für die Gleichheit aller Menschen.

That's both times a pointing finger. Without the article the meaning is about the same, but without that emphasis.

Comment: Thank you. Those are exactly the insights I needed.